# Using * in a sets in a python regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

In python 3.2.2 I confronted with strange errors when I try to use * in regex patterns. When * stads after / all is ok. But when I try to remove / from patter, this code falls down with error: **sre_constants.error: bad character range**

```
import re
foo = re.search("[^123+-/*]", "123+-/*w")
if foo:
    print("foo")
else:
    print("doo")
```

In the python docs I found that using * is acceptable without any backslashes or other stuff. However problem with code like this remains.

Comment: By the way, the [`re.DEBUG`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#re.DEBUG) flag can help resolving these things (especially verifying that an "accepted" regex does what you expect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't `*`, it's the hyphen-minus which represents a range in a character class, in this case all characters between `+` and `/` (`+,-./`). The invalid range occurs because `*` comes *before* `/`.

If you want to include a literal hyphen in a character class you have to either escape it or put it at the very end or start:

```
[^123+/*-]
```

Comment: I haven't enought reputation for voting up your question. But I think you must now that you help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The minus is causing the last characters to get interpreted as a character range. `[+-/]` acutally means "any of `+,-./`" (see the ASCII table). When you replace the `/` by `*`, you're creating the invalid range `[+-*]` because the ASCII code of the asterisk, 42, is less than the ASCII codes of the plus, 43.

The solution is simply escaping the minus (then it's not a range any more).

Comment: I got the staff about escaping. Thank you. Please, tell me what you think about moving hyphen on the last position in the set. Is it help me without escaping or not? Escaping makes code messy.

Comment: The hyphen at the last position will work. And yes, escaping is kinda awkward.
But when you're dealing with a larger project with 5, 10 or +20 coders with different levels of qualification and specialization, it's better to make the code as failure safe as possible: Keeping the backslash may avoid confusion (or even issues) when one tries to add another character.